# Fail to resolve spring-security-ldap 2.0.1 into Grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, spring-security, dependencies

Please help! I had a problem installing spring-security-ldap 2.0.1 into my Grails 2.4.4.
My BuildConfig.groovy is like such:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo"
}

dependencies {  
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:2.0.1"
}
```

And during resolve the following error is shown:

```
Error | Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:jar:2.0.1 in grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
```

It's not a connection/proxy issue cause other dependencies was resolved with no problem.

Anyway to resolve this? Any info/help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change dependency **from**

```
dependencies {  
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:2.0.1"
}
```

**To**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:3.0.2'
}
```

You can check [repo](https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-ldap/) of grails core `spring-security-ldap` plugin.

**Updated:**

```
plugins {

compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0.1"

}
```

Please refer [this](https://github.com/javazquez/Grails-Active-Directory-LDAP-example) link to other configuration

Above uses Grails 2.X and likely won't work with 3.X

Hope this will helps you

Comment: Same error. (In fact I tried 3.0.2 first, then I noticed their plugin page stating use ver 2.x.x for Grails 2 and version 3.x.x for Grails 3)

Comment: Thanks! It works, moving it into the plugins{} as -> compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0.1" had installed it.  I did not need to declare anything for it in dependencies{}.

Comment: Thanks. I updated answer. Hope someone also helps it :)